# Activate anaconda environment within docker container

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I am trying to programatically (within Python) replicate the anaconda environment I am working in locally in a Docker container. However, I want to make one Docker image capable of doing this for an arbitrary environment. I see the process looking something like:

1. Within my local environment, export the anaconda environment I am working in by using the `subprocess` Python module to run `conda env export >> environment.txt`.
2. Start up my Docker container (whose base image is `continuumio/anaconda:latest`), providing it the `environment.txt`. The python file the container runs should operate within the Anaconda environment specified by that `environment.txt`.

I know how to do step 1, but I don't see how I could do step 2; how can I, within a Python script, update the anaconda environment (and install the missing packages) in which it operates?